# Console logging a response from an API printing undefined

Tags: javascript, api

This is for an assignment to create a Jeopardy game using the jService api; I am walking through and console.logging to check myself, but when I log the answer below it prints undefined, while the question and title print to the console without issue. What am I missing?

```
async function getCategory() {
    for (let catID of catIDs) {
        // console.log(catID);
        const response = await axios.get('http://jservice.io/api/clues?category=' + catID);
        // console.log(response);
        let clueArray = [
            {
                question: response.data[0].question
            },
            {
                answer: response.data[0].answer
            }      
        ];

        let clue = {
            title : response.data[0].category.title,
            cluesArray: clueArray
        }
        console.log(clue.title);
        console.log(clue.cluesArray[0].question);
        console.log(clue.cluesArray[0].answer);    //this line logs undefined      
    }
    return clue;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `response.data[0].answer` is defined?

Comment: Can you show us what console.log(response) prints?

Comment: `answer: response.data[0].answer` should be directly under `question: response.data[0].question`, not in another object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let clueArray = [
    {
        question: response.data[0].question
    },
    {
      answer: response.data[0].answer
    }      
];
```

should be

```
let clueArray = [
  {
    question: response.data[0].question,
    answer: response.data[0].answer
  }    
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much; definitely a brain fart that I overlooked.

Comment: If you could mark that as the answer then, that would be great. It'll teach the downvoter.